Is the expression 花正好 temporal?
I have another question about the song 梦何处寻, whose lyrics are below.
陽光照樹梢　春來花正好
啊我歌我徘徊　啊處處聞啼鳥

昨夜夢魂飛　心事知多少
啊夢向何處尋　啊處處聞啼鳥

For whatever reason the expression in the first verse, 花正好, was striking to me as it seemed rather unusual but also very apt. I was understanding it to mean something like "just right", i.e. the flowers were just how I would have hoped them to be at that time, and hence exceptionally pleasing. I don't know if this is the result of my mental translation into an English expression, or if this is the sense that a Chinese reader would also have.
In my other question  on this song, two people translated this phrase in a temporal sense: "Flowers (came) just in time". Which also seems right, I hear people say things like 你来得正好 all the time.
So my question is, is this always and everywhere a temporal expression and my sense above an English translation artifact, or could it also be present in the original?
FWIW here is my attempt to translate the song.
On the branch tips shining I see the sun's warm light. Spring is here, and flowers are just right.
Oh I sing and wander, wander here and there. And oh! birdsong, birdsong everywhere.

Last night I dreamed my spirit flew, worries without end. You can't know how many thoughts contend.
Oh my dreams how can I, where can I find them here. And now oh! birdsong, birdsong everywhere.


好 has the meaning of 'finish', which extent to 'full bloom' for the flower

common expression 花好月圓 - "the flower blooms and the moon is full", (representing a happy time)

花好 = The flower is in full bloom

花正好 = The flower has just fully bloomed (Spring arrived, happy time has just begun)



春來花正好
This verse is to be read as a composite, though it is broken into two parts.
If 正好 is read in isolation, then yes, it could, generally, also mean "Just Right"
However, as the verse 春來花正好 though read as a composite phrase, is in two complementary parts, namely:-
First part -- 春來 = Spring has arrived;
Second part -- 花正好 = will now no longer be read as "Flowers are just right", but "Flowers have arrived just in time" in order to complement the First part of the verse, 春來, Arrival of Spring, meaning "Spring has arrived, so too have the Flowers (bloomed), right on time"
If the intended meaning of 花正好 is something to do with the beauty of the flowers, (which is usually the case as seldom do flowers be said to be "just right"), then some other expression like 花真美, or other appropriate expressions be used, i.e. 春來花真美, "The flowers with the arrival of Spring are so beautiful"
As you say, people always say things like 你来得正好 all the time, meaning that "You arrived just in time" (to do or participate in whatever)
